# Hyperledger first network sample error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am following this link [first-network](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html) to run hyperledger samples name `first-network`.

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04LTS**

`./byfn.sh -m generate` got successfully executed.

When I am trying to execute `./byfn.sh -m up` I am getting **error**

`2018-05-08 08:45:22.485 UTC [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp folder
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Channel creation failed !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========= ERROR !!! FAILED to execute End-2-End Scenario ===========

**Edits 1**: Adding docker compose files

[docker-compose-cli.yaml](https://pastebin.com/6QsgcrHP)

[docker-compose-couch.yaml](https://pastebin.com/2Y80LTRB)

[docker-compose-e2e.yaml](https://pastebin.com/Gmz8zgvi)

[docker-compose-couch-org3.yaml](https://pastebin.com/RcU2XK8F)

[docker-compose-e2e-template.yaml](https://pastebin.com/SDhFaPCE)

[docker-compose-org3.yaml](https://pastebin.com/VFKJHKGD)

Comment: Please share the docker-compose files so that we could further look into the configuration issues

Comment: Please check above , I have added docker compose files

Comment: Double check that you have the crypto-config directory created after you run cryptogen or use the startup byfn script and it contains the necessary generated msp directory structure for your components.

Comment: I also faced similar issue. Clearing volumes and networks by typing follwoing commands helped me:
docker network prune &&
docker volume prune

Answer (score 0):

Your crypto materials are not getting generated properly as required . Check that you have all the **Prerequisites** installed on the platform(s) I hope you have downloaded all the platform specific binaries https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh

This will make sure you have the correct **Cryptogen** and **Configtxgen** tools for creating crypto material,ca clients and channel configurations .