# Cannot create a channel by customizing the ./startNetwork.sh script?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I am very new to blockchain with Hyperledger. I am customizing the startNetwork.sh script. So I have created something like this.

```
# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

#removing all the containers
echo "#### Removing all the containers"
echo ""
echo ""
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
echo ""
echo ""

#prune the volumes
echo "#### Prune the network "
echo ""
echo ""
docker volume prune
echo ""
echo ""

#down the previously build networks
echo "##### Removing networks and containers #####"
echo ""
echo ""
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml down --volumes 
echo ""
echo ""

#Up the network
echo ""
echo "##### Network is under the build #####"
echo ""
echo ""
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
echo ""
echo ""

#starting the cli
echo ""
echo ""
echo "##### Starting the cli incase if it is sleep #####"
docker start cli
echo ""
echo ""

docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=PSPMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/psp.example.com/users/Admin@psp.example.com/msp" -e "CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.psp.example.com:7051" -e "CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/psp.example.com/peers/peer0.psp.example.com/tls/ca.crt" peer0.psp.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

But when I hit ./startNetwork.sh on the bash terminal it leaves me an error of

```
2019-03-18 06:42:52.162 UTC [main] InitCmd -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, folder "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/psp.example.com/users/Admin@psp.example.com/msp" does not exist
```

But when I issuing this command inside the cli container It was worked successfully. Can someone help me to modify this file in order to get rid of this error? Thank you!

Comment: hi there, I suspect the answers here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229686/hyperledger-first-network-sample-error and here -> will help you resolve your custom script path issues:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551179/hyperledger-fabric-peer-error

Answer (score 0):

cli expects a few crypto artifacts to interact with Fabric components. In the sample, they are generated, and **mounted into docker contains at specific path, and exported as env var**, so it can be invoked within the container. You'll need to do the same setup in bash in order to get it work. Check out how the *cli container* is defined in docker compose file (which might be overwhelming, and probably it's a better idea to do it in cli container)